# ElasticSearch - workaround of unique constraint

Tags: database, elasticsearch, unique-constraint

I am thinking about some smart workaround of **"no unique constraint"** problem in ElasticSearch.
I can't use `_id` to store my unique field, because I am using `_id` for other purpose.

I crawl Internet pages and store them in ElasticSearch index. My rule is, that url must be unique (only one document with given url in index) so as ElasticSearch doesn't allow to set unique constraint on one field, I must query index before inserting new page to check if there is already site with given url.

So adding new page to document looks like that:

1. Query(match) index in ES to check if there is document with given `url` field.
2. If not, I insert new document.

The solution has two disadvantages:

1. I must execute extra query to check if there is already document with given url. It slows down inserting process and generates extra load.
2. If I try to add 2 documents with the same url in short amount of time and the index doesn't refresh before adding second document, the second query returns, that there is no document with given url and finally I have two documents with the same url

So I am looking for something else. Please tell me if you have any idea or please tell me what do you think about such solutions:

Solution 1
To use other database system (or maybe another ES index with url in `_id`) where I will store only urls and I will query it to check if there is already url

Solution 2
2. To queue documents before inserting and to disable index refreshing when other process will process the queue and add queued documents to index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit upon one of the things that Elasticsearch does not do well (secondary indexes and constraints) when compared to some other NoSQL solutions. In addition to Solution 1 and Solution 2 I'd suggest you look at Elasticsearch Rivers:

> **Rivers**
>
> A river is a pluggable service running within elasticsearch cluster
>   pulling data (or being pushed with data) that is then indexed into the
>   cluster.

For example, you could use the MongoDB river and then insert your data into MongoDB. MongoDB supports secondary unique indexes so you could prevent insertion of duplicate urls. The River will then take care of pushing the data to Elasticsearch in realtime.

https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb

ES supports CouchDB officially and there are a number of other databases that have rivers too -

Comment: Thanks. I will use MongoDB to store urls, but i will not use River. I will sync data by myself. I have bad experiance with mongo->ES river.